# Enable input submit button when two checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, submit

I have a form and at the end of the form there are two checkboxes that must be checked in order to enable the submit button for the form.

I guess javascript would help me out here, but I am not that skilled.

Part of the code looks like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="confirm1" value="confirm1" >
<input type="checkbox" name="confirm2" value="confirm2" >

<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Rensa" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Skicka" disabled="disabled" >
```

Anyone who have an idea how the javascript would look be?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: add onclick, check if checkboxes are clicked, set disabled to false. Try to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution should looks something like this. Just check it for correct syntax:

```
<script>
function check(element) {
var cb1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
var cb2 = document.getElementById("checkbox2");
var sub = document.getElementById("submit");
if (cb1.checked == true  &&  cb2.checked == true)
    sub.disabled = false;
else
    sub.disabled = true;
}
</script>

<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="confirm1" value="confirm1" onclick="check();">
<input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="confirm2" value="confirm2" onclick="check();">

<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Rensa" >
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Skicka" disabled="disabled" >
```